# The exponential function is 2pi i periodic how come the domain only needs to Im(z) to be smaller than pi?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

In complex analysis we looked at the inverse functions for holomorphic functions. We proved that for f: $\Omega \subset \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ and $f'(z_0) \neq 0, z_0 \in \Omega$ there exists an open surrounding an U of $z_0$ and V of $f(z_0)$ and the inverse holomorphic function g: V $\to \Bbb{C}$. We then looked at the example of the exponential function $z \in \Bbb{C} \mapsto exp(z) \in \Bbb{C}$ which is holomorphic with derivative $\neq 0 $ there must exist an inverse function g (the natural logarithm). However what confuses me is that the prof. the specified the following: since $e^{2\pi i+ z} = e^z, z \in \Bbb{C}$ it suffices to only look at 
exp:$ \Omega = \{z \in \Bbb{C}, |Im(z)|<\pi\} \to \Bbb{C} \setminus(]-\infty,0])$ the latter makes sense since the logarithm can't intake negative values however why $|Im(z)|<\pi$ and not $|Im(z)|<2\pi$ since it is $2\pi i$ periodic?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|Im(z)|< 2\pi$ allosw $z = \pi i$ and $z = -\pi i$ at the same time (with pretty good margin). Which is bad, because of the periodicity you just mentioned.

So we could require $0<Im(z)<2\pi$, or just shove everything a bit down the imaginary axis and require $-\pi < Im(z)<\pi$. Either one is equally valid, really, but the latter one can be written more compactly, as $|Im(z)|<\pi$.

Ultimately, it's a matter of preference between the two (or any other possibility, but those two are the most common). Your book / lecturer prefers the latter.